# Como ampliar el area del hover

Tags: css3, hover

Estoy animando una lista con :hover en CSS, pero al moverse los li se me detiene la animacion a la mitad, existe alguna solucion mediante CSS?

Aqui el codigo:

```css
li:hover {
  width: 100%;
  animation: desliza 1s 0.5s 2 linear, desaparece 1s 0.5s 2 linear;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes desliza {
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes desaparece {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>testeo a</li>
  <li>testeo b</li>
  <li>testeo c</li>
  <li>testeo d</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mejor a que te refieres con que "se detiene a la mitad"? Cual es el comportamiento que esperas?

Answer (score 5):

Esto es mejor que lo hagas con una transición, así al quitar el :hover vuelve suavemente a su estado inicial. Y para evitar que se pierda el foco del :hover, puedes no mover el propio elemento donde haces el :hover sino su contenido

```css
 li{
          overflow:hidden;
}
li:hover {
  width: auto;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;

}
 li div {
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 transform: translatex(0);
opacity:1;
}
 li:hover div {
 transform: translatex(100px);
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>testeo a</div></li>
  <li><div>testeo b</div></li>
  <li><div>testeo c</div></li>
  <li><div>testeo d</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya ha comentado otro usuario puedes usar `transition` para lo que quieres hacer. Si no quieres cambiar el HTML puedes animar la indentación, así el `li` no se desplaza y no pierdes el `:hover` cuando el texto se mueve:

```css
li {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  text-indent: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>testeo a</li>
  <li>testeo b</li>
  <li>testeo c</li>
  <li>testeo d</li>
</ul>
```